# Prove that this function is bijective (Proving Denumerability)

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

In order to prove that any subset $A$ from $\mathbb N$ is denumerable, I have to prove that the function $f:\mathbb N \to A$ defined by $$f(1)=\min{A}, \quad f(n+1)=\text{the smallest number in }A>f(n)$$
is bijective.

The first thing that came to my mind is to prove that $f$ is invertible but I have no idea how to do it, so I should prove that $f$ is injective and surjective. I think that the injective part is easy than the surjective one, so I started with it,

Suppose $f(a)=f(b)$, with $a\ne b$, then we have 2 cases :

**Case 1**

Either $a$ or $b$ is $1$, so suppose (WLOG) $a=1\implies f(a)=\min{A}$ and $$f(b)=f(c+1)=\text{the smallest number in }A>f(c)$$
I stopped here because I don't know how to continue.

Comment: By construction $f(n) < f(n+1)$ and then by induction it follows that $n <m$ implies $f(n) < f(m)$ from which injectivity is immediate.

Comment: As to surjectivity: suppose $f[\Bbb N] \neq A$ and let $m$ be the minimum of $A\setminus f[\Bbb N]$. Then consider $\{a \in A:a < m\}$ which is empty or has a maximum....

Comment: I didn't get the surjective part @HennoBrandsma

Comment: Think about it some more

Comment: It seems like $m=\min{A-f[\mathbb N]}$ came out of nowhere, that's why I can't understand the proof.

Comment: You cannot skip an element of $A$ because if you picked one before the smallest skipped one it would have been an image next step. Hence the minimum (exploitating the well order).